# Hide Based on DEVICE / OS and NOT screen size

Tags: html, css

This may not be possible based on my search, but is there a way to hide a div based on DEVICE instead of screen size?

I have a client who wants a video in the header banner. That was no problem. Autoplay videos however are often blocked by mobile devices though to conserve data. "Also no problem," I thought. I'll just have two header banners - video div that will hide except on desktop-sized screens and image banner that be hidden for desktops.

What I forgot is that an iPad in landscape mode has more than enough pixels for the browser to see it as a desktop. So, when on an iPad, even a mini, in landscape mode, you get this massive empty div because it technically is "there" (as opposed to a hidden div) because the browser is saying it should be shown, but the DEVICE is blocking the video.

If it was just the iPad mini, I could solve this by changing the pixel required to see the desktop version as 1025 (as the iPad mini is 1024px on its longest side). However, once you go to any normal-sized tablet, there is no way by browser-size between a desktop and a tablet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi! takes a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile_Device_Detection

Comment: Hey! Thanks @hashtag-assist - that didn't exactly answer my question, but it did get me going in the right direction. I'll give you a hat tip in the answer I found. It's user agent sniffing, which seems to be frowned upon, but until iOS either stops blocking auto play videos or at least stops being the only one to do it, I'm kinda stuck having to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hashtag-assist, I was able to get searching in the correct direction and thought I would share my answer in case anyone else is looking for it. You can detect OS, which is close enough to what I wanted.

I had to use agent sniffing in Javascript, which isn't ideal, but until iOS stops being the only OS to block autoplay content, I'm kind of stuck with it. I used the Javascript to hide the video on iOS and display an image that is hidden on other operating systems. Here is the code for any that want to use it:

First, the HTML:

```
    <html>
    <video muted playsinline loop autoplay width="100%" height="auto" id="bannermovie">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="your_movie_url" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <img src="YourAlternateImageBanner" alt="" width="100%" style="display:none;" id="StillHero"/>
    </html>
```

Next, the Javascript:

```
    <script>
    var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
    if (isIOS) {
      document.getElementById("bannermovie").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("StillHero").style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
```